# Applications using JDBC vs Applications using Web services

Tags: web-services, http, jdbc, web, https

What is the difference between the apps using JDBC and the apps using web services?

Why people prefer to use web services than the using a direct JDBC connections?
what would be the key contributing factors that can help me,to get started on web services?

I made some research on it, before posting this questions,that web services are inter-operable, im looking for any details that help me to dug down deep into web-services

Comment: This is definitely a discussion that is off-topic for SO. You might want to start by reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: I made some research on it, before posting this questions,that web services  are inter-operable, im looking for any details that help me to dug down deep. Because here I always find good people with a better understanding.

Comment: Please improve your question. Add above comments in your question. It's very broad topic to discuss so better narrow it down as per your interest.

Answer (score 2):

it all depends on the needs.
What is the cloud today.
Everything in the cloud, accessible from your phone, pc, anywhere you are.
Imagine this:

You have to enter a record and analyze information from software that will run around the world ....
Think about whether you do it with JDBC; all you would have to enable IP to query your server ...
That's not good, either for you or for your hosting provider ...

Now with Web Service, SOAP communication.
security is supported, you can control responds to the request and who is not ...

Answer (score 1):

Apps using JDBC, uses actual connection to database. Each time you want to create update, delete or select any data, you will make a connection and perform your operations on db directly using queries.

Ask yourself, do you really want to provide your db connection and access to each of your client. That is not wise.

Web service based app follows service oriented architecture. They provide quite good abstraction over your db. Most important things about webservices are interoperability and portability which is very difficult to achieve using simple jdbc.